# How can you form a new dataframe reflecting the changes of values in an original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

If you could peek into the future and know exactly what stocks to buy and sell given their entire price history, how would you implement it, given constraints that your only values of `Shares` is `1000`, `0`, and `-1000`? You also start with `1000` shares. You can also trade `2000` shares to get from `1000` directly to `-1000` and vice versa.

I want to take a dataframe `df_prices` like this:

```
              JPM
2008-01-02  38.47
2008-01-03  38.20
2008-01-04  37.33
2008-01-07  37.71
2008-01-08  36.21
2008-01-09  36.72
```

and transform it into `df_trades`:

```
            Symbol Order    Shares
2008-01-02  JPM    NOTHING  1000
2008-01-03  JPM    HOLD     1000
2008-01-04  JPM    HOLD     1000 
2008-01-07  JPM    BUY      0
2008-01-08  JPM    SELL     -1000
2008-01-09  JPM    HOLD     0
```

using this code:

```
if df_prices['JPM'].shift(1) > df_prices['JPM'] & curr_hold == 0:
    df_orders['Order'] = 'SELL'
    df_orders['Shares'] += 1000
elif df_prices['JPM'].shift(1) < df_prices['JPM'] & curr_hold == 0:
    df_orders['Order'] = 'BUY'
    df_orders['Shares'] -= 1000
elif df_prices['JPM'].shift(1) > df_prices['JPM'] & curr_hold == -1000:
    df_orders['Order'] = 'HOLD'
elif df_prices['JPM'].shift(1) < df_prices['JPM'] & curr_hold == 1000:
    df_orders['Order'] = 'HOLD'
```

It doesn't work however. I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: How do I transform the first data frame into the second.

Comment: What is `curr_hold`?

Comment: It’s an initial value set to 0. I may have to change that bit as well. It’s supposed to say how many shares you have initially. I believe I should set it to 1000 and then change my code from there.

Comment: From your code it doesn't seem like it is possible for you to attain this output. Unfortunately, without a working example of how your code is supposed to run with your logic, it isn't clear _how_ you expect to get from your input to expected output, which is the most important thing here, you've not mentioned.

Comment: Instead of forming the entire data frame I just want to set the share values based off the prices. I believe that’s all I need if I have a given prices. I’ll add one more line that does the rest of the transformation.

Comment: Do should realise that `df_orders['Shares'] += 1000` will modify the entire column, not just a single cell. Are you calling this code in a loop? Otherwise it seems incorrect.

Comment: Yes, and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Could I use `np.where`?

Comment: I don't think you can, because it appears you want the result of previous computation for the next row. You'll need to iterate, but I still can't figure out what you want based on the fact that the code you provided is missing a lot of important details.

Comment: Check out my previous question.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 it's not clear what is the value of `curr_hold`. Can you please edit that?

Comment: Curr_hold is how many shares of JPM I currently have. I start off with a 1000

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

This is sufficient:

```
for i in range(len(df_prices)):
    if i == len(df_prices) - 1:
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Date', df_prices.index[i])
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Order', 'BUY')
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Shares', 0)
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Symbol', symbol)
        break
    if df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i + 1]][symbol] > df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i]][symbol] and curr_hold == 0:
        curr_hold += 1000
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Date', df_prices.index[i])
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Order', 'BUY')
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Shares', 1000)
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Symbol', 'JPM')
    elif df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i + 1]][symbol] < df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i]][symbol] and curr_hold == 0:
        curr_hold -= 1000
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Date', df_prices.index[i])
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Order', 'SELL')
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Shares', 1000)
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Symbol', symbol)
    elif df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i + 1]][symbol] > df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i]][symbol] and curr_hold == -1000:
        curr_hold += 2000
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Date', df_prices.index[i])
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Order', 'BUY')
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Shares', 2000)
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Symbol', symbol)
    elif df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i + 1]][symbol] < df_prices.loc[df_prices.index[i]][symbol] and curr_hold == 1000:
        curr_hold -= 2000
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Date', df_prices.index[i])
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Order', 'SELL')
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Shares', 2000)
        df_orders.set_value(i, 'Symbol', symbol)
```

although I could probably modularize a lot of it.